# "as we make what we have do the job. " What does this mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I just happened to be reading [**this page,**](https://www.tribune.org/when-things-go-north/) and there is a line,

> We have another going due north mantra here in Boston. I cannot tell you how proud I am of our stewardship here. Our budget team and our staff — up and down the line — make us proud month after month **as we make what we have do the job.** In times like these, I can’t brag on that enough. Good people doing a good job on a good northern mis­sion.

What does the bold line mean?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means they get their work done without having to buy new equipment or spend additional money.

(What we have) refers to the equipment they already own. They make that get the job done instead of buying new things.